# Find the time spend walking down a hill, given the time spent walking up the hill and the up/down walking patterns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lance walks up a hill. For every 40 minutes of walk he takes 10 minutes to rest. When he walks down the hill, he instead takes 5 minutes of rest for every 40 minutes of walk. Lance walks downhill at a speed 2 time as fast as that he walks uphill. If he spends 4 hours walking up the hill, how much time does he spend walking down the hill?

I don't know how to approach this, maybe someone can prod me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$40$ minutes of walking uphill $\quad\Rightarrow \quad 10$ minutes of rest
$40$ minutes of walking downhill $\quad\Rightarrow \quad 5$ minutes of rest

$x$ = uphill speed
$2x$ = downhill speed

$4$ hours ($240$ minutes) to walk up the hill

You can simply count your way to $240$ minutes: $40$ minute walk $+$ $10$ rest $= 50$ minutes. You can do this $4$ times in the $240$ minutes with the last $40$ minutes requiring no additional rest to get up the hill. You can simply take the $10$ rest at the top of the hill before going back down.

What this does, is show you that the hill from bottom to top requires $200$ minutes of walking at a rate of $x$ mph.

Downhill you walk at a rate $2x$ and cut your rest time down to $5$ minutes per $40$ minutes walked. So, for every $2$ minutes walk before, you now walk only $1$ minute.

Using this information, calculate how many minutes of walking are needed to get down the hill then add in the number of $5$ minute rest periods required to make it down for that amount of time.

Comment: You accepted that very quick. Take some time to see that you understand it and that what I said makes sense. I could have made a mistake. Let me know what you end up determining the final answer is.

Comment: @Vincent Is the answer 210 minutes?

Comment: If it took $200$ minutes to go uphill, and you go downhill twice as fast and rest half as long, wouldn't you expect the answer to be less than $200$?